# Is it possible to pause/rewind in VLC's dummy interface?

Tags: command-line, vlc-media-player, streaming

I got it working what I initially wanted. I have a desktop computer, which I use as a "streaming server". I send all the VLC streaming commands to it, and my desktop computer sends the video to the STB. The connection between my laptop and desktop computer is established with a tool called PsExec. Here's the command I'm sending to my desktop computer:

```
"vlc" -I dummy --dummy-quiet --directx-volume=0.00 "C:\Users\User\video.ts" :sout=#duplicate{dst=udp{mux=ts,dst=239.9.14.2:1234},dst=dummy} :no-sout-rtp-sap :no-sout-standard-sap :sout-all :ttl=1 :sout-keep
```

Everything works, I can stream content using my laptop, but I don't have any control over it (I don't have the regular VLC GUI). You're probably wondering why wouldn't I just stream the whole thing with VLC GUI not dummy interface - get a VNC client or even TeamViewer and start streaming and control VLC that way. Well, there are other people who'd like to use the desktop computer as well - that's why I don't want to distract them in any way.
But I'd like to have control over playing content - I want to pause it, rewind it, fast-forward it, etc. Though if I won't get this working, it wouldn't be the end of the world, hehe. I'm glad I got this working even that way.

Thanks for any suggestions on how I could accomplish this!

Comment: re " there are other people who'd like to use the desktop computer as well - that's why I don't want to distract them in any way." <-- i've heard that linux running vnc lets you have multiple desktops with vnc, though windows doesn't. And perhaps linux with its multiple desktops would give you gui access without distracting others

Comment: perhaps not relevant, but related to some control- i've just managed to change volume. `c:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC>.\vlc.exe -I dummy --global-key-vol-down=a c
:\crp\a2.mp3   Maybe the dummy interface is the term for the command prompt (the one spawned, not the one the command is issued from)

c:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC>  `  when the new cmd prompt comes up keep tapping 'a' decreases the volume.  But that's not so unintrusive graphically.

Comment: I managed to get it working thanks to VLC's web interface.

Comment: you can post an answer to your oqn question and accept it(they let you post an answer to your own question and then come back in about 2 days and accept it) but even if you don't want to come back in 2 days, it's still useful if you post your answer.